# Getting DatabaseError: multiple default values specified for column

Tags: sql, postgresql, django-south, askbot

I can't figure out what to do to avoid this error whenever I try to make a migration using South in one of my Django projects:

ERROR:

Running migrations for askbot:

> - Migrating forwards to 0006_auto__del_field_tagplus_tag_ptr__add_field_tagplus_id__add_field_tagpl.
>
> askbot:0006_auto__del_field_tagplus_tag_ptr__add_field_tagplus_id__add_field_tagpl
>
> FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: ALTER TABLE "tagplus" ADD COLUMN "id" serial NOT >NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT -1;
> The error was: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "tagplus"
>
> Error in migration: >askbot:0006_auto__del_field_tagplus_tag_ptr__add_field_tagplus_id__add_field_tagpl
> **DatabaseError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "tagplus"**

MIGRATION FILE 0006 CODE (Partial):

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):

def forwards(self, orm):
    # Deleting field 'TagPlus.tag_ptr'
    db.delete_column(u'tagplus', u'tag_ptr_id')

    # Adding field 'TagPlus.id'
    db.add_column(u'tagplus', u'id',
                  self.gf('django.db.models.fields.AutoField')(default=0, primary_key=True),
                  keep_default=False)

    # Adding field 'TagPlus.name'
    db.add_column(u'tagplus', 'name',
                  self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(default=0, unique=True, max_length=255),
                  keep_default=False)
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

I Guess the error has something to do with this choice I was prompted while creating the migration file.

```
 ? The field 'TagPlus.tag_ptr' does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL.
 ? Since you are removing this field, you MUST specify a default
 ? value to use for existing rows. Would you like to:
 ?  1. Quit now.
 ?  2. Specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now
 ?  3. Disable the backwards migration by raising an exception; you can edit the migration to fix it later
 ? Please select a choice:
```

I selected 'specify one-off value' and I set this value to `0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are anyways saying `keep_default=False`. So remove that `default=0` from your code

```
   db.add_column(u'tagplus', u'id',
                  self.gf('django.db.models.fields.AutoField')(primary_key=True),
                  keep_default=False)
```

Per SQL it should be (remove the `NOT NULL`)

```
ALTER TABLE tagplus ADD COLUMN id serial PRIMARY KEY
```

See this document which explains the reason behind this error http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Comment: No luck with this, I'm getting: Error in migration: askbot:0007_auto__del_field_tagplus_tag_ptr__add_field_tagplus_id__add_field_tagpl
DatabaseError: type "serial" does not exist

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in SQL, is there any way I can remove the NOT NULL using the python code and not raw SQL?.

Comment: @AndreuC., nice question!!! have no idea about Python. Moreover, I have answered this question solely cause it's is tagged with postgreSQL. Sorry.. If the answer isn't much help to you ... then I should delete it. let me know.

Comment: @AndreuC., in that case try accepting it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to note:

1. Django will use 'id' as the default primary key if you haven't manually set one before, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields).
2. Postgres does not really have a 'serial' type. To resolve this issue, try to replace:

   ```
   # Adding field 'TagPlus.id'
   db.add_column(u'tagplus', u'id', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.AutoField')(default=0, primary_key=True), keep_default=False)
   ```

with:

```
    # Adding field 'TagPlus.id'
    if 'postgres' in db.backend_name.lower():
        db.execute("CREATE SEQUENCE tagplus_id_seq")
        db.execute("SELECT setval('tagplus_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tagplus))")
        db.execute("ALTER TABLE tagplus ADD COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('tagplus_id_seq'::regclass)")
        db.execute("ALTER SEQUENCE tagplus_id_seq OWNED BY tagplus.id")
    else:
        db.add_column(u'tagplus', u'id', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.AutoField')(default=0, primary_key=True), keep_default=False)
```